# Check for number of occurrences in json element matching a criteria, python

Tags: python, json

I have the following code which shows me the number of "Names elements in a Json file":

```
import json
with open('names.json') as f:
    item_dict = json.load(f)
    print len(item_dict['Names'])
```

What i want to do is to find the number of times a specific attribute in the Name element is equal to a specific word.

```
"Names": [
        {
            "PId": 2,
            "Name": "John",
            "Surname": "Snow"
        }
```

I want to find how many times is in the file a Name element with `Surname = Snow`.

Help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension

**Ex:**

```
print(sum([1 for i in item_dict['Names'] if i["Surname"] == "Snow"]))
```

**Output:**

```
1
```